# Control order of pathlib and string concatenation

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a directory I want to save files to, saved as a `Path` object called `dir`. I want to autogenerate files names at that path using string concatenation.

The only way I can get this to work in a single line is just through string concatenation:

```py
dir = Path('./Files')
constantString = 'FileName'
changingString = '_001'

path2newfile = dir.as_posix() + '/' + constantString + changingString

print(path2newfile) # ./Files/Filename_001
```

... which is overly verbose and not platform independent.

What I'd want to do is use pathlib's `/` operator for easy manipulation of the new file path that is also platform independent.  This would require ensuring that the string concatenation happens first, but the only way I know how to do that is to set a (pointless) variable:

```py
filename = constantString + changingString
path2newfile = dir / filename
```

But I honestly don't see why this should have to take two lines.

If I instead assume use "actual" strings (ie. not variables containing strings), I can do something like this:

```py
path2newfile = dir / 'Filename' '_001'
```

But this doesn't work with variables.

```py
path2newfile = dir / constantString changingString
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I think the base question is **how do I control the order of operators in python?** Or at least make the concatenation operator `+` act before the Path operator `/`.

Keep in mind this is a MWE. My actual problem is a bit more complicated and has to be repeated several times in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use parentheses surrounding your string contatenation:

```
path2newfile = dir / (constantString + changingString)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using Python f-strings?

It seems like your real-world example has a "template-y" feel to it, so something like:

```
path / f"constant part {variable_part}"
```

may work.

Comment: I hadn't considered it, but that is definitely a good solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). 
It's both platform-independent and you can plug the desired path parts as arguments.